# loss of Internet traffic via network security device

Tags: networking, router, dns, troubleshooting, openwrt

I can't get any Internet traffic in bridge mode. I'm using network security device named "Shield" made by Itus Networks which went out of business.

The device is based on a Cavium Octeon Dual-Core MIPS64 (2x1.0 GHz) processor, with a custom board containing three gigabit ethernet ports, 1gb of DDR3 RAM and 4gb of eMMC internal storage, and a RJ45 Serial Console port. Early models also contained a SD Card slot. The system was shipped running OpenWRT 15 - Chaos Calmer, with customizations that create a security device capable of running OpenVPN, E2Guardian, Snort, Squid, Suricata, StrongSwan and other internet security applications.

The system has an external slider switch to select from different operating modes: Router, Bridge or Gateway. I'm using a Asus RT-N66U router with the Shield

Here is link for the admin guide http://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/05/01/itus-shield-admin-guide/preview/page/1/

Here are part of the logs

```
Thu May 5 11:07:38 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[5413]: forwarded yourhost.example.com to 192.168.1.1
Thu May 5 11:07:38 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[5413]: query[AAAA] yourhost.example.com from 127.0.0.1
Thu May 5 11:07:38 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[5413]: forwarded yourhost.example.com to 192.168.1.1
Thu May 5 11:07:43 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[5413]: query[A] yourhost.example.com from 127.0.0.1
Thu May 5 11:07:43 2016 daemon.info dnsmasq[5413]: forwarded yourhost.example.com to 192.168.1.1
```

any help would be appreciated

Here is photo of DNS on network security device

[image: DNS on network security device setting]

Comment: So basically it is a IPS.  So it has a hardware switch, to switch between modes, so what mode is it operating in? Have you confirmed within its configuration pages, that you are indeed, running in bridge mode?  I am not sure what your question is though.  Its clearly redirecting everything to localhost, which means, your not getting any sort of DNS information.

Comment: Hi,  Ramhound yes it has IPS and Web Filter and Firewall I'm using Bridge mode I'm using it with my Asus RT-N66U router I look at the Status page and it shows UTM Bridge

Comment: While connected to this device, can you access, the configuration page on the ASUS?  Have you verified the DNS configuration of this device, is set to, the router?

Comment: what can I do to get DNS information to pass thru the network security device

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: HI, Yes I can  configuration page on the ASUS

Comment: Looking at the  network security device the DNS address is the same as my ASUS IP did you need to post the logs from the ASUS ?